# What is the equivalent of the LONG type of Oracle DB in Java?

Tags: oracle, spring-boot, hibernate, stored-procedures, spring-data-jpa

I have a problem when calling a stored procedure from oracle db with a LONG type parameter in spring data jpa

my stored procedure inputs structure is like below

[image: image of my sp paramters]

and i call it from spring data jpa with structure below

```
    @Procedure(name = "my-sp-name")
    ResultSet getReport(
            @Param("AMOUNT_IN") Long amountIn,
            @Param("AMOUNT_OUT") Long amountOut,
            @Param("FROM_DATE") Long fromDate,
            @Param("TO_DATE") Long toDate,
            @Param("P_INPUT") Character[] pInput,
            @Param("P_BRANCH_CODE") Long pBranchCode,
            @Param("P_HEAD_BRANCH_CODE") Long pHeadBranchCode,
            @Param("P_STATUS") Long pStatus,
            @Param("REPORT_TYPE") Long reportType
    );
```

and I got the following exception again and again with different types that oracle recommended in its document like char[], Character[], and Clob

```
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'my-sp-name'
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

Comment: Why do you create a procedure with `long` parameter type? It is deprecated for decades. [In 10g reference](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/server.101/b10759/sql_elements001.htm#sthref114): *Do not create tables with LONG columns. Use LOB columns (CLOB, NCLOB, BLOB) instead. LONG columns are supported only for backward compatibility*

Comment: Yes you are right, Thank you for your helpful comment but I didn't use LONG type for our data, our dba did it and now I need to implement it in our application java application,do you have a solution for this exception I got in spring data jpa?